# Logarithmic Representation

Tags: javascript, html, math, web, graph

I have values ranging from 0 to 22050. I am plotting them linearly on an HTML canvas. While the graph is displaying correctly - I want to show them on a logarithmic scale - same values but the x axis should represent 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000(instead of 0 - 22050 linearly).
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a charting library?  Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot log10(y) instead of y, but label ticks with 10^v instead of v.

You can implement log10(y) as log(y)/log(10). So Math.log and Math.pow should be enough in JavaScript.

For integers v this gives you powers of ten, but if you want other points in between with nice labels, you will need to use reasonable fractions (e.g. log10(2) and log10(5)), not merely round to one decimal or some such.